# If a line bundle and its dual both have a section (on a projective variety) does this imply that the bundle is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, vector-bundles

Is there any reason that, on a projective variety X, if a line bundle L has a (non-zero) section and also its dual has a section then this implies that L is the trivial line bundle?

Comment: Your question is not a duplicate (and I like this question), but perhaps the answer should be accompanied by this link which finishes the proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1397283/346324

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason for $L$ to be trivial  and here it is:

Let $0\neq  s\in \Gamma(X,L)$ and $0\neq  \sigma\in \Gamma(X,L^*)$ be two non zero sections.
Then $s\otimes \sigma\in \Gamma(X,L\otimes L^*)=\Gamma(X,\mathcal O)$ is a constant since $X$ is complete: $s\otimes \sigma =c\in k$ (the base field).

Now, since $s$ and $\sigma$ are non-zero there is a non-empty  open subset $U\subset X$ on which both do not vanish and on which $s\otimes \sigma=c $ does not vanish either: in other words  $c\neq0\in k$ .
Since  $s\otimes \sigma =c\neq 0$, a non-zero constant,  vanishes nowhere we conclude that  *a fortiori* $s$ vanishes nowhere, so that $L$ is trivial, as announced,  since $ s\in \Gamma(X,L)$ .

Comment: Hence, we have to suppose that $X$ is an integral scheme, proper over $k$. In this case $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O})$ is a finite field extension of $k$.

Comment: @Andrea: yes. When a user mentions projective varieties I try  to interpret his question in the most elementary way possible. It is then generally possible for more advanced readers to adapt the solution  to a more sophisticated context,  if they so wish.

Comment: thanks to both of you. I tried to play with tensoring them together but didn't think to restrict to some open subset!