# An orientable line bundle is always trivial?

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, line-bundles

In general, there exist non-trivial orientable bundles. But if we only consider line bundles, then orientable bundles are always trivial bundles. (Similarly, non-trivial bundles are always non-orientable bundles.)
Is this statement true?

I got this conclusion from the following question and answer:
[If a line bundle admits a non-vanishing section then it is trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397283/if-a-line-bundle-admits-a-non-vanishing-section-then-it-is-trivial). If a line bundle admits a non-vanishing section, then it conforms to the definitions of trivial bundle and orientable bundle at the same time.

Comment: The twisted $I$ bundle over the Möbius-band is non trivial and is a solid torus, however as a disk bundle over the circle is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(E,B,L)$ be an orientable line bundle, this means there exists trivializations $U_{i}$ such that $\forall i; \phi_{U_{i}}:\pi^{-1}(U_{i}) \mapsto   U\times \mathbb{R}$ is fiberwise orientation preserving, denote by $g_{i}$ the inverse of this map, pick a partition of unity $P_{i}$ of the base space subbordinated to the trivializations (such a partition exists whenever $B$ is assumed to be paracompact). Define the map $s:B\mapsto E$ by the formula $s(b)=\sum P_{i}(b) g_{i}(b,1)$ where the sum is (necessarily finite) and is over the $U_{i}$ to which $b$ belongs.

Remark that $\forall b\in B,s(b)$ is never zero because preserving orientation between a one dimensional vector space and $\mathbb{R}$ means that $g_{i}(b,1)$ is always one "the same side" for every $b$ and every $I$.

This proves that an orientable line bundle is necessarly trivial.the other direction is easy.